# The screens of BottomNavigationBar is not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation-bar

I have a bottomNavigtionBar with jetpack compose but the screens are not showing when I navigate between it, it's showing the bottom bar with a blank white page

[image]

I have three screens Home, Profile and Settings

```
@Composable
fun HomeThirdScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Home",
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.White
        )

    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewHomeThirdScreen() {
    HomeThirdScreen()
}
```

Profile Screen

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Magenta),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Profile",
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.White
        )

    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewProfileScreen() {
    ProfileScreen()
}
```

Settings screen

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Gray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Settings",
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.White
        )

    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewSettingsScreen() {
    SettingsScreen()
}
```

and this **BottomBarScreen** class

```
sealed class BottomBarScreen(
    val route:String,
    val title:String,
    val icon:ImageVector
){
    object Home:BottomBarScreen(
        route = "home",
        title = "Home",
        icon = Icons.Default.Home
    )

    object Profile:BottomBarScreen(
        route = "profile",
        title = "Profile",
        icon = Icons.Default.AccountCircle
    )

    object Settings:BottomBarScreen(
        route = "settings",
        title = "Settings",
        icon = Icons.Default.Settings
    )
}
```

and this BottomNavGraph

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavGraph(navHostController: NavHostController) {

    NavHost(navController = navHostController, startDestination = BottomBarScreen.Home.route){

        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Home.route){
            HomeThirdScreen()
        }
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Profile.route){
            ProfileScreen()
        }

        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Settings.route){
            SettingsScreen()
        }
    }

}
```

and this main screen code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    val navHostController = rememberNavController()

    BottomNavGraph(navHostController = navHostController)

    val screens = listOf(
        BottomBarScreen.Home,
        BottomBarScreen.Profile,
        BottomBarScreen.Settings
    )

    val navBackStackEntry by navHostController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }


        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {
                screens.forEachIndexed { index, bottomBarScreen ->

                    NavigationBarItem(selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any {
                        it.route == bottomBarScreen.route } == true,
                        label = { Text(text = bottomBarScreen.title) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedItemIndex = index
                            navHostController.navigate(bottomBarScreen.route)
                        },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = bottomBarScreen.icon,
                                contentDescription = bottomBarScreen.title
                            )
                        })
                }
            }
        }) {
            it.calculateTopPadding()
            it.calculateBottomPadding()
           it.calculateEndPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr)
           it.calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr)


        }
}
```

and finally, I called the MainScreen Composable here

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                ) {
                MainScreen()
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand the concept of a `NavHost` it's not just a function that controls navigation its also a **composable** that acts like a container o for it's destinations.
The problem in your code is that you are calling `BottomNavGraph` outside your main composable container in your case `Scaffold` so even though you are navigating to the screen it will not show because of the `Scaffold` shadowing it.
You should do it like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable

fun MainScreen() {

val navHostController = rememberNavController()

val screens = listOf(
    BottomBarScreen.Home,
    BottomBarScreen.Profile,
    BottomBarScreen.Settings
)

val navBackStackEntry by navHostController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
    mutableIntStateOf(0)
}


    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
        NavigationBar {
            screens.forEachIndexed { index, bottomBarScreen ->

                NavigationBarItem(selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any {
                    it.route == bottomBarScreen.route } == true,
                    label = { Text(text = bottomBarScreen.title) },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedItemIndex = index
                        navHostController.navigate(bottomBarScreen.route)
                    },
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = bottomBarScreen.icon,
                            contentDescription = bottomBarScreen.title
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
    }) {
        it.calculateTopPadding()
        it.calculateBottomPadding()
       it.calculateEndPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr)
       it.calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr)
BottomNavGraph(navHostController = navHostController)

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I am a newbie in jetpack compose and this is my first try, thanks for clarification :)

Comment: @DrMido well for a first try i would say you did a fantastic job at least it's far better than my first try keep up the good work